# jQuery slideToggle doubling up..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am working on a mobile menu for this site:

http://giamberardino.com/_beta/team.html

When I click on "Showcase" it's toggle the slide of the entire menu as well as .mbl-dropdown.  I would like it to just toggle the slide of .mbl-dropdown when .mbl-showcase is clicked on.

Where am I going wrong??

```
               <nav class="mobile_menu">
                    <ul id="menuItems">
                         <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="company.html" > Company</a> </li>
                        <li class="mbl-showcase">Showcase
                        <ul class="mbl-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">General Contracting</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CUSTOMIZED MILLWORK</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">BUILDING RESTORATION</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="team.html"  class="active"> Team </a></li>
                        <li><a href="careers.html" >Careers </a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

$(".mobile_menu_button").bind('click', function() {
    $('.mobile_menu').slideToggle();
}); 

$(".mbl-showcase").bind('click', function() {

    $('.mbl-dropdown').slideToggle();
    $('.mobile_menu').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to make it clear in your mind:
you have to hide the dropdown menu **NOT** the whole navbar , so you need to give the .mbl-dropdown a display:none.
then you just want to make the jquery code like that :

```js
$(".mbl-showcase").on('click', function() {
    $('.mbl-dropdown').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.mbl-dropdown{
  display:none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="mobile_menu">
                    <ul id="menuItems">
                         <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="company.html" > Company</a> </li>
                        <li class="mbl-showcase">Showcase
                        <ul class="mbl-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">General Contracting</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CUSTOMIZED MILLWORK</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">BUILDING RESTORATION</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="team.html"  class="active"> Team </a></li>
                        <li><a href="careers.html" >Careers </a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

that means if you click on the element with class .mbl-showcase wich is "Showcase" the dropdown will show if it is hidden and it will be hidden if it is shown and that what does **toggle** mean.

make sure you check again the toggle property http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
I hope I helped you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation.  It all certainly makes sense.  I updated my code to match your explanation, but the problem still remains that clicking on "Showcase" toggles the entire mobile menu div as well.  I don't want that to happen when the menu is expanded already.

Comment: what do you mean by the entire mobile menu div?
if you mean the whole nav then you're wrong try that code and you'll see it works , however, if it is not what you mean please I'd like a clarification and thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="mobile_menu">
                    <ul id="menuItems">
                         <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="company.html" > Company</a> </li>
                        <li class="mbl-showcase">Showcase
                        <ul class="mbl-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">General Contracting</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CUSTOMIZED MILLWORK</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">BUILDING RESTORATION</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="team.html"  class="active"> Team </a></li>
                        <li><a href="careers.html" >Careers </a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

.mbl-showcase ul{

  display:none;
}


$("#menuItems li").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find(".mbl-dropdown").slideToggle()
});
```

Fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/zeqy9zfo/

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the help.  The same is true in your solution, as above.  Clicking on "Showcase" still causes the entire menu to slide up.